# Session Timeout Issue while running Jmeter scripts recorded for iPad native application

Tags: ios, jmeter, performance-testing

I am getting " “Your user session has been lost, and you have been automatically logged out.  Please log in again.” while running the scripts which is recorded for JMeter, for an iOS native application. Anyone face this issue for any iOS device? How to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Anna.

Comment: please refer : http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Comment: I have followed the exact steps mentioned in  jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf. After recording if I ran the test it will execute without any issue for sometime. If I execute the same test plan, after 2 hours, again I am getting message "Your user session has been lost, and you have been automatically logged out.  Please log in again"

Comment: Looks session issue of website which you are testing.

Comment: What do you mean by "session issue of website". I didn't get you point. :(

Comment: Basically in website developer sets limited time for login which we called session time. if user log in and then ideal for that time it automatically logout..so I think that is set in site for which you are doing load testing.

Comment: But in my scenario, user is not idle. After login immediately triggering transactions. I think you are confused since I mentioned 2 hrs. My scenario is very simple. Login to the app and click on few tabs. After recording the steps. Im saving the test plan and running the recorded test. It will take less than a minute to complete execution. But if I ran the saved test after 2-3 hours or a day. I will get the session time out message

Comment: Still this issue is not resolved. :( But I could see message "The current time on this device appears to be incorrect. Go to Settings to verify Date &amp; Time is correctly set for your time zone, then try again." I think because of this issue getting session timeout for rest of the requests. Any idea why this message is coming?